# Xamarin Forms (Android) - Associate app with custom file type

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wish to associate the file extension '.etd' with Android so that files with this extension will open the app when tapped.

I've been all over the internet and there are many combinations of code to implement, yet absolutely nothing works unless I use a generic file type such as '.txt'.

The 'Open with...' menu will appear with the following IntentFilter declaration in MainActivity.cs when I use a .txt file:

`[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = @"text/plain")]`

However, the code below, and numerous permutations and variations, don't do anything (trying to open an .etd file gives an 'unable to open file' error):

`[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataScheme = "file", DataHost = "*", DataMimeType = "*/*", DataPathPattern = ".*\\\\.etd")]`

Also, nothing I can find explains what to do if I eventually do get the file association working either, i.e. how to access the file and work with it. *Edit: I've worked this last bit out now (by renaming my files to .tsv and using 'text/tab-separated-values' as the DataMimeType), so now I just need to know how to associate .etd files with my app.*

Comment: Have you try to use other way open the file? Does the .etd file could be opened?

Comment: Opening a file from within the app is itself quite straightforward. You don't need file type associations to do that. What I don't know is how to access the file that opened the app, partly because I don't see how to make that happen and partly because there's no documentation on it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to access the .etd file which associated with app that this extension will open the app when tapped not achive how deso the .etd file associate with app?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If I'm in the 'My Files' app for example (or any file browser, Whatsapp, an email, etc.), I want tapping the .etd file to open my app. It should work whether my app is currently running or not.

I've got this working perfectly fine with generic file types but not any that I've made up.

PS, I've worked out how to get the file path and work with the file so I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.etd` file extension do not have the matching `DataMimeType`. So we could not associate the file extension '.etd' with Android.

There are too many types so that I could not upload all of them.  For more details, please check the link. https://github.com/khellang/MimeTypes/blob/master/src/MimeTypes/MimeTypes.cs.pp

Here are the types for `e` part and `t` part for your reference.

```
static MimeTypes()
    {
        s_fallbackMimeType = DefaultFallbackMimeType;

        s_typeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
           
            { "ear", "application/java-archive" },
            { "ecma", "application/ecmascript" },
            { "edm", "application/vnd.novadigm.edm" },
            { "edx", "application/vnd.novadigm.edx" },
            { "efif", "application/vnd.picsel" },
            { "ei6", "application/vnd.pg.osasli" },
            { "elc", "application/octet-stream" },
            { "emf", "application/x-msmetafile" },
            { "eml", "message/rfc822" },
            { "emma", "application/emma+xml" },
            { "emz", "application/x-msmetafile" },
            { "eol", "audio/vnd.digital-winds" },
            { "eot", "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" },
            { "eps", "application/postscript" },
            { "epub", "application/epub+zip" },
            { "es", "application/ecmascript" },
            { "es3", "application/vnd.eszigno3+xml" },
            { "esa", "application/vnd.osgi.subsystem" },
            { "esf", "application/vnd.epson.esf" },
            { "et3", "application/vnd.eszigno3+xml" },
            { "etx", "text/x-setext" },
            { "eva", "application/x-eva" },
            { "evy", "application/x-envoy" },
            { "exe", "application/octet-stream" },
            { "exi", "application/exi" },
            { "exr", "image/aces" },
            { "ext", "application/vnd.novadigm.ext" },
            { "ez", "application/andrew-inset" },
            { "ez2", "application/vnd.ezpix-album" },
            { "ez3", "application/vnd.ezpix-package" },                              
            { "t", "text/troff" },
            { "t3", "application/x-t3vm-image" },
            { "t38", "image/t38" },
            { "taglet", "application/vnd.mynfc" },
            { "tao", "application/vnd.tao.intent-module-archive" },
            { "tap", "image/vnd.tencent.tap" },
            { "tar", "application/x-tar" },
            { "tcap", "application/vnd.3gpp2.tcap" },
            { "tcl", "application/x-tcl" },
            { "td", "application/urc-targetdesc+xml" },
            { "teacher", "application/vnd.smart.teacher" },
            { "tei", "application/tei+xml" },
            { "tex", "application/x-tex" },
            { "texi", "application/x-texinfo" },
            { "texinfo", "application/x-texinfo" },
            { "text", "text/plain" },
            { "tfi", "application/thraud+xml" },
            { "tfm", "application/x-tex-tfm" },
            { "tfx", "image/tiff-fx" },
            { "tga", "image/x-tga" },
            { "thmx", "application/vnd.ms-officetheme" },
            { "tif", "image/tiff" },
            { "tiff", "image/tiff" },
            { "tk", "application/x-tcl" },
            { "tmo", "application/vnd.tmobile-livetv" },
            { "toml", "application/toml" },
            { "torrent", "application/x-bittorrent" },
            { "tpl", "application/vnd.groove-tool-template" },
            { "tpt", "application/vnd.trid.tpt" },
            { "tr", "text/troff" },
            { "tra", "application/vnd.trueapp" },
            { "trm", "application/x-msterminal" },
            { "ts", "video/mp2t" },
            { "tsd", "application/timestamped-data" },
            { "tsv", "text/tab-separated-values" },
            { "ttc", "font/collection" },
            { "ttf", "font/ttf" },
            { "ttl", "text/turtle" },
            { "ttml", "application/ttml+xml" },
            { "twd", "application/vnd.simtech-mindmapper" },
            { "twds", "application/vnd.simtech-mindmapper" },
            { "txd", "application/vnd.genomatix.tuxedo" },
            { "txf", "application/vnd.mobius.txf" },
            { "txt", "text/plain" },
            
            
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't believe that's the answer. It sounds like you're saying that someone decided at a particular point in time that these are the only file extensions anyone is ever going to be allowed to use from now on, and that if you want to use a different one you're screwed. That's madness.

Comment: For now, .etd extension is not suppported by the MimeTypes. It decideds by the developers. Sorry for that.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It seems I'll just have to put up with being forced to use an inappropriate file extension. It's incredibly naff that MIME types, which are for the internet, scuppers my ability to open a file that has nothing to do with the internet unless I use a MIME type from an arbitrary list that some short-sited developers decided on. Anyway, thanks for your help, Wendy.

Comment: @RobotHead Glad to help. If this reply help you, do not forget to accept as answer. Thanks~ And if you still want the MimeType for .etd extention, you could try to post your requirement on github with the link i provided in reply.

Comment: Oh I could do that yes!

Comment: Do not forget to accept as answer. Thanks~

Comment: Please can you edit the answer to make it clear that the answer to my question is that it isn't possible?

Comment: I have edited the reply to clear the answer.